# Why forEach keeps incrementing in js? But in console looks perfect though.

Tags: javascript, json, twitter-bootstrap

I want to develop a simple contact list application. With static json, ajax request and using js and bootstrap. I want to make each row with a profile picture on the left and a name next to it. Each name and picture from json. Instead of this, the following happens: 1st row ok, but 2nd row contains double, 3rd row triple and 4th row 4 times names and pics.

What's the problem? Bonus: how can I alphabetically sort names? .sort() not works for me.

JS code:

```
var profiles = document.getElementById('profiles');
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'data.json');
request.onload = function() {
  var contacts = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
  contacts.forEach(function(data){
    $('.pre-scrollable').prepend('<div class="row media"></div>');
    $('.media').prepend('<div class="media-body"></div>');
    $('.media').prepend('<div class="media-left"></div>');
    $('.media-left').prepend('<img class="media-object" style="width:60px">');
    $('.media-object').attr('src', data.picture);
    $('.media-body').prepend('<p>' + data.name + '</p>');
    console.log(data.name);
  });
};
request.send();
```

data.json:

```
    [
      {
        "name": "Richard",
        "address": "Cell",
        "mobile": "687 30 79",
        "picture": "1.jpg"
      },
      {
        "name": "Daniel",
        "address": "Sarvar",
        "mobile": "616 58 42",
        "picture": "2.jpg"
      },
      {
        "name": "Adam",
        "address": "Budapest",
        "mobile": "178 24 98",
        "picture": "3.jpg"
      },
      {
        "name": "Brad",
        "address": "Szeged",
        "mobile": "812 25 66",
        "picture": "4.jpg"
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is simple:

When you do

```
$('.media')
```

You ask " select all the balise that has a media css class" 
So the selector will select all medias (even previous you added in your js script, so for the frist loop it's ok but not the other)

To resume you do in you forEach:

// 1st Time
 - Select pre-scrollable balise -> OK

- Add a .media (so there is one .media in document)
- Select .media (1 balise selected)
- ...

// 2nd Time
 - Select pre-scrollable balise -> OK

- Add a .media (so there is two .media in document)
- Select .media (2 balises selected)
- ...

...

Comment: I've searched for a day for solutions and it was that "easy", thanks for pointing me out. Works fine now. So the solution is that use id's instead of classes. By the way, do you have any idea how to sort the names alphabetically? Where should I put .sort() ?

Comment: You can simply put following code before foreach
`contacts.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.name > b.name;
}`

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is define a function to create your html dom template and insert the variable names.  Using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), you can easily do this.

This ensures you don't need to use jquery to traverse and select elements in the dom, as you're building an entire subtree dom node yourself.

```
function templateBuilder(data) {
    return template = `
        <div class='row media'>
            <div class='media-body'>
                <p>{data.name}</p>
            </div>
            <div class='media-left'>
                <img class='media-object' style='width:60px;' src='{data.picture}'>
            </div>
        </div>
    `;
}

request.onload = function() {
    ...
    contacts.forEach(function(data) {
        $.pre-scrollable.append(templateBuilder(data));
    });
};
```